# What would prevent a PHP die() from working? On my computer die() is not working

Tags: php, php-8, php-8.1

This is on MacOS with PHP 8.1.10 installed via homebrew ...

Just a blank index.php code in it with only this code ...

```
<?php
die('We Should Just Die Here');

throw new \RuntimeException('This exception should never be seen');
?>
```

And .. render in my browser to see ...

```
<br />
<b>Fatal error</b>:  Uncaught RuntimeException: This exception should never be seen in /path/to/public/index.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 /Users/my-user/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php(234): require()
#1 {main}
  thrown in <b>/path/to/public/index.php</b> on line <b>4</b><br />
```

Same story if I run it command line (taking valet out of the equation) ..

```
$ php index.php

Fatal error: Uncaught RuntimeException: This exception should never be seen in /path/to/public/index.php:4
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /path/to/public/index.php on line 4
```

I have already tried ...

- Upgrading PHP
- Re-installed Valet
- Composer updating everything

In my roughly 800 years of writing PHP code I have never seen anything like this. Please if anyone has any help I'm interested.

Comment: This question/answer does not help anyone. The effect is mentioned in the documentation. No need to duplicate it here. Voting to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found it. I installed the `php-uopz` extension a while back. I had completely forgotten about that.

`pecl uninstall uopz` fixed this for me.

Thank you for the rubber ducking stack overflow ;P

Comment: I just wanted to say that ;) It's mentioned in the PHP documentation, in a public comment..

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. I was trying to recreate it, obviously to no success.

Comment: Why would you install `php-uopz`?

Comment: There are use cases for php-uopz .. usually for me it involves mocking data or functionality for unit tests.